# Spring: Reference bean in @import file during annotation based Configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations

I have two spring Configuration classes A and B. Beans in B are imported in A using the @import annotation, like this

```
@Configuration
@Import({B.class})
public class A {
    private BBean bbean;

    @Bean
    public ABean aBean() {
        // need to reference B's bean over here
        return aBean()// after referencing B's bean
    }
}

@Configuration
public class B {
    @Bean
    public BBean bBean(){
       return new BBean();        
    }
}
```

How would I reference the bean bBean while creating bean aBean? One would think that @Required or @Autowired would work here, but it does not :(

**UPDATE - What I'm trying to do here is run unit tests using TestNG and maven. When I try to reference the 'Autowired' bean, maven hangs, possibly in an infinite loop or waiting for the bean to be loaded.**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
13:15:42,427  INFO eans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: 315 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]
13:15:42,589  INFO nnotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner: 210 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
13:15:42,671  INFO ontext.support.GenericApplicationContext: 495 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@45d6a56e: startup date [Fri Feb 15 13:15:42 PST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
13:15:42,769  INFO ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 623 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=repositoryConfig; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/abc/pagg/ddee/repository/config/RepositoryConfig.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=serviceConfig; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [com/abc/pagg/ddee/service/config/ServiceConfig.class]]
13:15:42,983  INFO ion.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: 139 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
13:15:43,027  INFO ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: 557 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@66b51404: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,serviceConfig,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,sqlSessionFactory,org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,commonConfig,propertiesConfig,repositoryConfig,iusRestManager,localCacheClientAdapter,memcachedClientAdapter,s3Adapter,dataSource,userMapper]; root of factory hierarchy  <<--- hangs right here
```

**UPDATE - Real code here**

```
@Configuration
@Import({CommonConfig.class})
public class ServiceConfig {
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceConfig.class);
private org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration propertiesConfig;

@Autowired
public void setPropertiesConfig(org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration propertiesConfig){
    this.propertiesConfig = propertiesConfig;
}

public ServiceConfig() {
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
 --->   dataSource.setDriverClassName(propertiesConfig.getString("jdbc.driver")); <----
    //dataSource.setUrl(propertiesConfig.getString("jdbc.url"));
    //dataSource.setUsername(propertiesConfig.getString("jdbc.username"));
    //dataSource.setPassword(propertiesConfig.getString("jdbc.password"));

    return dataSource;
}
```

The bean propertiesConfig is defined in CommonConfig. I get an invocationTargetException on the highlighted line because propertiesConfig is null. The dataSource bean keeps on getting instantiated in a loop.

Comment: Are you sure `@Autowired` doesn't work? I use it with success in this scenario, except that I reference auto-discovered beans during component scanning.

Comment: @Autowired should work, I use it and the same scheme in several apps.

Comment: re: your update, if you find that Spring is hanging while creating the bean factory, I would try to set some breakpoints and attach a debugger to find out exactly where it is hanging. What version of Spring? Do you see the same behavior if you run the test in an IDE as if you run it with `mvn` from the command line?

Comment: It's mavent that is actually hanging. Attaching a debugger would help. But yes, I'm seeing the same behaviour when I run the test from Eclipse using Debug As -> TestNG Test

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I have a similar problem now. No hangs, but by debugging I can see that the init order is funky. I have the DataSource annotated with @Autowired, but it seems it only gets initialized in the imported config AFTER I actually need it in the main config.This was specifically a problem  with jUnit testing, but I expect the same behaviour in production. Any one got any tricks?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `@Import` mentions that you should use `@Autowired` in cases like the one you describe:

> @Bean definitions declared in imported @Configuration classes should be accessed by using @Autowired injection. Either the bean itself can be autowired, or the configuration class instance declaring the bean can be autowired. The latter approach allows for explicit, IDE-friendly navigation between @Configuration class methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `@Autowired` causing your problem. From where you experience the hang, I expect you have a bean that does something on startup that's not finishing in a timely manner. Since the bean's initialization never finishes, Spring can't continue starting up. Some kind of network communication is most likely, as those have a bad habit of hanging indefinitely with no output unless specifically configured otherwise. Pull a stack dump when the JVM is hung, and see what your threads are doing. Otherwise, attach a debugger, and manually pause the JVM for the same effect.

Comment: This did get me on the right track, please see the updated question above.